# HAproxy 1.5 fails to proxy properly to backend

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I'm puzzled why this FE doesn't seem to connect me to the BE through my HAproxy:

```
defaults
   mode http
   log global
   option  httplog
   option  dontlognull
   source 0.0.0.0 usesrc clientip  # transparent proxy mode

frontend fe-kb
   bind :8081 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/ssl-key.pem
   default_backend be-kb

backend be-kb
   server afnB afnB:1080 check
```

I get this in HA http log:

```
Jan  9 17:25:04 localhost haproxy[17266]: <ip redacted>:51396 [09/Jan/2016:17:24:44.544] fe-kb~ be-kb/afnB 31/0/-1/-1/20036 503 212 - - cC-- 0/0/0/0/3 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
```

I can connect fine from HAproxy CLI (selinux is disabled):

```
[root@hapA ~]# telnet afnB 1080
Trying 10.45.69.14...
Connected to afnB.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.9.9
Date: Sat, 09 Jan 2016 16:40:44 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 612
Last-Modified: Wed, 09 Dec 2015 15:05:19 GMT
Connection: close
ETag: "5668432f-264"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the default route wasn't through my HAproxy and as I was trying to do transparency of the source IPs well ;)

Thanks for watching!

Comment: Can you please tell me how you configured the default route for your backend server. I'm facing the same issue with tomcat server as my backend.